# Solve for $t$, $12.5 = 50(e^{-0.4t}-e^{-0.8t})$

Tags: calculus

$12.5 = 50(e^{-0.4t}-e^{-0.8t})$

I tried:

$$12.5 = 50(e^{-0.4t}-e^{-0.8t}) \Leftrightarrow 12.5 = 50(\frac{1}{e^{\frac{2}{5}t}}-\frac{1}{e^{{\frac{4}{5}t}}}) \Leftrightarrow 12.5 = 50(\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{e^{2t}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{e^{4t}}}) \Leftrightarrow \\ 12.5 = \frac{50}{\sqrt[5]{e^{4t}}} - \frac{50}{\sqrt[5]{e^{4t}}} \Leftrightarrow 12.5 = \frac{50\sqrt[5]{e^{4t}} - 50 \sqrt[5]{e^{2t}}}{\sqrt[5]{e^{4t}}\sqrt[5]{e^{2t}}} \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next? Am I doing it correctly?
Also, this method seems too complicated. Is there a simpler way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=e^{-0.4·t}$, then your equation reduces to the quadratic equation
$$
12.5=50(x-x^2)
$$
Solve that for $x$ and compute $t=-2.5·\ln(x)$.